# Hibernate no session in ItemProcessor (Spring Batch)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I'm having an issue with trying to access Hibernate entity relationships as part of an `ItemProcessor` while running a Spring Batch job. The `ItemProcessor` is part of a chunk-based step. As far as I can tell the `ItemProcessor` runs in a transaction and therefore *should* be able to lazily load entity relationships.

### The issue

I'm getting the following exception as part of the `ItemProcessor` logic:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [org.powo.model.registry.Organisation#1] - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
        at org.powo.model.registry.Organisation$HibernateProxy$OFnEWoXa.getIdentifier(Unknown Source)
        at org.powo.model.solr.BaseSolrInputDocument.build(BaseSolrInputDocument.java:39)
        at org.powo.model.solr.TaxonSolrInputDocument.<init>(TaxonSolrInputDocument.java:67)
        at org.powo.model.Taxon.toSolrInputDocument(Taxon.java:1091)
        at org.powo.job.reindex.TaxonToSolrInputDocumentProcessor.process(TaxonToSolrInputDocumentProcessor.java:20)
        at org.powo.job.reindex.TaxonToSolrInputDocumentProcessor.process(TaxonToSolrInputDocumentProcessor.java:13)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:303)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:202)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Here's the `ItemProcessor` for reference (and within the `toSolrInputDocument` logic is where the entity relationships are traversed):

```
@Component
public class TaxonToSolrInputDocumentProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Taxon, SolrInputDocument> {
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Override
  public SolrInputDocument process(Taxon item) throws Exception {
    return item.toSolrInputDocument(context);
  }
}
```

And I'm using an `org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernatePagingItemReader` as the reader.

### What I've tried

I've tried the following but none of the solutions have prevented the error above:

- using a `JpaPagingItemReader` instead of `HibernatePagingItemReader` but this still has the same issue
- using `@Autowired` to get a `SessionFactory` and then doing `openSession`/`closeSession` around the code which traverses the entity relationships

Because of the data model I'm not able to fetch all relationships in one query so I need to use a stateful session (though I would like to fetch some!).

Comment: Can you update your sample with the method from where the process is being called. If it is being called within a transaction and the entity is not detached within that persistent context there is no reason you would get a lazy initialization exception.

Comment: It's being called by Spring Batch as part of a chunk-based step in a batch job.

Comment: How and from where are you managing the db transaction from the application? Are you @Transactional annotation? Ideally when spring initiates a db transaction a persistent context is bound with it. From within that method you need to make your object attached to that persistent context (there are several ways to do so). And before exiting from that transactional method if you try to get the list item you shouldn't get lazy exception.

Comment: Because this is running as part of a Spring Batch chunk-based step I think Spring is managing the transaction - it certainly is when doing the reading from the database. The documentation says that the transaction is opened when the read starts and closed when the read starts and closed when the write committed - therefore it should be open when the processor runs (hence why I'm confused). I think it might be to do with the XML configuration - I tested this on a fresh Spring Boot project and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've now resolved this - in the end changing to `JpaPagingItemReader` did the trick. I'm not sure why it didn't work previously, although I did find that setting any kind of `taskExecutor` did seem to immediately break the lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK every step (read, process, write) creates a separate transaction for every chunk that is processed, so if your `ItemReader` does not initialize an association that is needed in the processor or writer, you will run into this error because the entities become detached when the entity manager is closed after the transaction commit. I don't know if it is possible to tell Spring to keep an entity manager around for the whole process, but if you want to rely on lazy initialization, you will have to figure this out.

I would recommend you to make sure that you use proper join fetches though, to avoid the need for lazy initialization i.e. `select t from Taxon t join fetch t.organization o`, or even better, use a DTO approach so that you don't have to care about lazy initialization at all.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Taxon.class)
public interface TaxonDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    OrganizationDto getOrganization();

    @EntityView(Organization.class)
    interface OrganizationDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TaxonDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TaxonDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<TaxonDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: Thanks for your comment Christian! I'd heard a bit about Blaze before. Unfortunately this is a legacy project so migrating the data access layer isn't really feasible for us at the moment. The other problem is that there are a _lot_ of relations that we'd have to load, and some of them are many-to-many. Because of the volume of data this means we'd have to do pagination in memory (which can't happen because it immediately exceeds heap space). Thank you for the alternative though, it looks a bit nicer than writing everything in JPQL!

Comment: No need for pagination in memory. Blaze-Persistence supports pagination perfectly down to the SQL level. Also, with `MULTISET` fetching you can avoid JDBC result set explosion due to *-to-many fetching.